# Blazer WebAssembly DevTools console is completely disabled

Tags: console, devtools, blazer

I have created a very simple Blazor Web Assembly app to learn more about Blazor.

I noticed nothing was getting registered in the DevTools console.  Then I noticed the console tab content was completely blank, not even a prompt. This ended up being true for both Chrome and Edge.

I have been up and down settings for DevTools and VS2022 (v.17.4.4) tools/options.  It is as if the console has been disabled. Does anybody know what is going on here?

[image: Screen capture of client app in Chrome]

Comment: I see now that the console output is being redirected to VS Output window. Where is this choice made that disables the WebTools console?  It isn't just getting the console.log lines, I also do a lot of debugging by inspecting variables in the console, and doing calls from there.